# Form Accessing using C / Web Browsing

Tags: c, http

I was wondering if there was a http C library which allowed a C program to access web forms, submit them, and navigate websites using links, which could almost mimic a web browser. Also a nice tutorial with some code snippets would be wonderful.

Thanks.

Ps. Running Windows 7 servicepack 1

Comment: You are accurately describing [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. That's precisely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!